# Pretty: true некоректно работает в gulp-pug

Tags: gulp, pug

Всем привет, компилирую pug через gulp. Функция выглядит так:

```
function html() {
return src(path.src.pug)
    .pipe(pug({ pretty: true }))
    .pipe(webphtml())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}
```

Компиляция происходит, но выходе получаю вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал вариант без pretty и как и ожидалось результат - html в одну строку без пробелов. То есть видно что что-то происходит, но результат не такой, как надо(нужный результат - "красивый" html).

Comment: На скриншоте видно, что между тегами разное расстояние, у вас есть обработчики после этого таска? Я использую pug с этой же настройкой и проблем нет.

Comment: Других обработчиков нет, плюс к тому же опытным путём я выяснил, что всё портит `.pipe(webphtml())`. Без него всё круто, но просто его удалить как по мне не вариант.

Comment: Вы используете pug и вместо webphtml() можете поступить как и я - написать миксин в pug

Comment: Спасибо, так и поступлю. Хотя хотелось бы понять в чём проблема

Comment: webphtml не обновлялся 4 года и репозиторий на github удалён.

Comment: Охотно вам верю, просто плагин сам рабочий если без PUGа